# Sometimes Images not loading properly

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, browser

Sometimes images are not loading properly in my website. Not completely. Lets say page includes 15 images. Two or three images not loading properly. Showing like this. When I refresh page, all images loading fine.

(Browser cache disabled)

[image]

The strange thing is this. If I inspect not loaded images using dev tools, get image url and paste it into new tab. Image is there!

I just want an idea why this is happening. Is this common issue? or bad host? long css file? or other issue?

This website contains more than 13,000 images stored in db.

Comment: check ur network tab in browser

Comment: Checked. It shows (Failed) in status

Comment: Then it may be server side issue, .... timeout or something else

Comment: Only status bar showing failed(ERR_CONNECTION_RESET) but image seems loading properly. https://imgur.com/wTXL873